# How to integrate a long key press into a list?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android, I have a list view and i'm planning to have a long key press on it then an alert view will ask the user if he wants to delete the chosen row.

Answer (score 2):

Register context menu for listview.

For Example,

http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/